# Comments in migrated question

Tags: support, migration, comments

I've just noticed [a question migrated from SO](https://serverfault.com/q/389438/47187) to which I had [added a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593399/how-to-make-tls-the-preferred-secure-connection-in-iis-7?noredirect=1). The OP had replied to it, but only his comment is now visible.

Is keeping only the OP's comments the normal behaviour?

There were a few links/pointers that should have been of interest for this question (I thought they were not sufficient for a full answer), and it makes his comment sound a bit awkward, since he's answering mine.

**EDIT:**

I've reposted a slight variation of my initial comment. I've noticed that the second comment had disappeared, but I'm not sure whether the OP deleted it or if it was someone else.

The overall question, it seems, is that when the comment contains a link to another question (or something else) on the site where the question is to be migrated, the comment is deleted altogether.

I understand it makes sense to delete a comment that says:

```
Voting to migrate to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)
```

but not:

```
Voting to migrate to ServerFault.
By the way, this is similar to https://serverfault.com/q/314874/47187 and ...
```

Assuming that `https://serverfault.com/q/314874/47187` is the same as `https://serverfault.com/` sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where your comment went; it doesn't seem to have ever come over. It's not even in the deleted list.

I'm guessing it's because you mentioned you were migrating it to Server Fault. My guess is that comments that mention a migration target are removed under the assumption that they were *only* a comment along the lines of `Off Topic belongs on Server Fault` which is kind of a useless comment when it actually gets here.

Because of this, I'm going to migrate this to meta.stackoverflow where hopefully it will get developer attention.

Comment: For future reference, no need to migrate - we keep an eye on all metas. :)

Comment: Also, yeah. I believe comments that mention the destination site will be removed in the migration in an attempt to cut down on noise.

Comment: @AnnaLear Argh, I've been deleting those by hand...

Comment: It's only if they include a link

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, I can understand why there would be an automatic rule to delete comments that talk about the migration itself, but I don't quite follow the rationale for removing comments with links.

Comment: @Bruno I meant it's only if they include a link to the target site. So "migrate to serverfault" won't get deleted, but "migrate to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)" will

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, ah, I see, but mine didn't really include a link to SF this way: it linked to a specific related (but not duplicate) question.

Comment: @Bruno It included a link to SF; that's all that matters